# WPF data bind with XML document

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, combobox

So the past year ive been working with android and as some of you might know all static String values in android are saved in the String.xml file.

Now i am currently working on a WPF project and in this project i have a Combobox. The values that this combobox is containing will NEVER change!

Because of this i was wondering if you could bind the combobox data in an XML file that contains all of the String values that the combobox contains.

My question is split into two small pieces:

1. is it possible to bind the data of a combobox with an XML document and is it even recommended to do so? and if so How do i do it?
2. If its possible how will you rective the "option" that the user selects from the combobox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing analogous to "all static string values saved in a string.xml file" in .NET programming, so forget about that.

There are many ways you can do this, up to and including creating your own strings.xml file, loading it at runtime and binding to the result.

Or, you could do it quick and simple.  If you want to do it via binding, create a type and add your strings to it.

```
namespace HerpDerp
{
    public static class Strings
    {
        public static string[] ComboLol {get;set;} // must be a Property
        static Strings()
        { 
            ComboLol = new string[]{"Lol", "kthx", "bai" };
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can reference this from xaml using the [Static markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx).

```
<ComboBox xmlns:derp="clr-namespace:HerpDerp"
          ItemsSource="{x:Static derp:Strings.ComboLol}" />
```

Or, hell, just add them directly

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem>Lol</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>kthx</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>bai</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Depends on your requirements with the list.  If it never changes, second is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

Binding values from a XML is not possible. But if you already know the values to be displayed, then you can do something like this.

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="MyCombo">
        <ComboBoxItem>Item1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

If you are familiar with MVVM you can handle selectedItem using a ViewModel; else you can access "MyCombo" from your form/control class.